# How to use bind1st and bind2nd?

Tags: c++, stl, binding

I would like to learn how to use binding functions.
Here is the idea:
I have this function which takes to parameters:

```
void print_i(int t, std::string separator)
{
        std::cout << t << separator;
}
```

And I would like to do:

```
std::vector<int> elements;
// ...
for_each(elements.begin(), elements.end(), std::bind2nd(print_i, '\n'));
```

But it does not work !

Here is what I get:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.3/backward/binders.h: In instantiation of ‘std::binder2nd<void ()(int, std::string)>’:
main.cpp:72:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.3/backward/binders.h:138: error: ‘void ()(int, std::string)’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/include/c++/4.3/backward/binders.h:141: error: ‘void ()(int, std::string)’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/include/c++/4.3/backward/binders.h:145: error: ‘void ()(int, std::string)’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/include/c++/4.3/backward/binders.h:149: error: ‘void ()(int, std::string)’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/include/c++/4.3/backward/binders.h:155: error: ‘void ()(int, std::string)’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/include/c++/4.3/backward/binders.h:140: error: field ‘std::binder2nd<void ()(int, std::string)>::op’ invalidly declared function type
/usr/include/c++/4.3/backward/binders.h: In function ‘std::binder2nd<_Operation> std::bind2nd(const _Operation&, const _Tp&) [with _Operation = void ()(int, std::string), _Tp = char]’:
main.cpp:72:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.3/backward/binders.h:164: error: ‘void ()(int, std::string)’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, _Funct = std::binder2nd<void ()(int, std::string)>]’:
main.cpp:72:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_algo.h:3791: error: no match for call to ‘(std::binder2nd<void ()(int, std::string)>) (int&)’
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I could use functor, but it is quicker to use binding.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not related to the question, so a small comment instead.
Shortest code to output a range is probably copying it into `ostream_iterator`, e.g. `std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The argument to `bind2nd` must be an [`AdaptableBinaryFunction`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/AdaptableBinaryFunction.html). A plain binary function does not fulfill this requirement (an adaptable function required typedefs for its return and argument types, a plain function type does not provide any typedefs). You could use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) which is probably the better choice anyway.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of an AdaptableBinaryFunction ?<br>Thanks

Comment: `std::ptr_fun` can convert binary function into `AdaptableBinaryFunction`: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ptr_fun.html

Answer (score 26):

You need to use a Copyable/Refrencable object, the following works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

void print_i(int t, std::string separator)
{
   std::cout << t << separator;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> elements;
   std::string delim = "\n";
   for_each(elements.begin(), 
            elements.end(),
            std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(&print_i),delim));
   return 0;
}
```

Normally you can get the same effect by simply doing the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> elements;
   std::copy(elements.begin(),
             elements.end(),
             std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,"\n"));
   return 0;
}
```

Also assuming you have access to TR1 in the STL you're using, its always best to revise/replace any uses of bind1st and bind2nd with std::bind

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the following steps:

1. create a struct (or class) that inherits from std::binary_function

2. define your predicate function in the operator() member function of the struct created in step 1

3. use bind2nd to bind an appropriate value to the struct created in step 1

I have done all this in an example. You can read the article and download the complete code on the following link: [bind and find](http://www.waqqasfarooq.com/waqqasfarooq/useful-code-snippets/stl-bind-and-find-algorithm-example)

Comment: Welcome to SO ! don't hesitate to include code, there is an option in the edit mode the button looks like that:`{}`, and having a short explicative code example is always good, like `class A{public: bool operator()(const B& b){ doSomething(); return true;}`... just an example :-)

Answer (score 1):

These functions are deprecated since C++11 and removed in C++17. As mentioned in one comment above, the better solution now is to use `std::bind` and the placeholders:

```
void callable(int a, int b);
auto f = std::bind1st(&callable, 42); // returns a 1-arg function
```

becomes:

```
// returns a 1-arg function
auto f = std::bind(&callable, 42, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Comment: Although you are technically right, one should use lambdas instead of `std::bind` variants anyway — it's a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Personally I sometimes find `std::bind` more readable than lambdas, depending on the surrounding code. This is only a preference though, I agree both work fine.