# C++ functor binding

Tags: c++, templates, bind, functor

i tried to use the old bind2nd function in this way:

```
template<typename T>
class printer
{
public:
  void operator()(T a, string& kd)
  {
        cout<<a<<endl;
  }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   string nme = "J-dar";
   auto f1 = bind2nd(printer<int>(),nme);

   //f1(5);
   return 0;
}
```

but i get a lot of errors:

```
required from here
error: no type named 'first_argument_type' in 'class printer<int>'  class binder2nd        ^
error: no type named 'second_argument_type' in 'class printer<int>'    typename _Operation::second_argument_type value;                                              ^
error: no type named 'second_argument_type' in 'class printer<int>'    binder2nd(const _Operation& __x,    ^
error: no type named 'result_type' in 'class printer<int>'    operator()(const typename _Operation::first_argument_type& __x) const    ^
error: no type named 'result_type' in 'class printer<int>'    operator()(typename      _Operation::first_argument_type& __x) const    ^
required from here
error: no type named 'second_argument_type' in 'class printer<int>'    typedef typename _Operation::second_argument_type _Arg2_type;
```

from what i can see it's all correct so i don't really know what is going on.           ^

Comment: Close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418756/how-to-use-bind1st-and-bind2nd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First of all**: I would recommend using abandoning `bind1st()` and `bind2nd()`, which are deprecated in C+11, and in general the obsolete support for functional programming of the C++03 Standard Library.

You should rather use C++11's [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), since it seems you can afford that - judging from the fact that you are using the `auto` keyword:

```
#include <functional>

// ...

auto f1 = std::bind(printer<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, nme);
```

---

This said, just for the record, the deprecated `std::bind2nd()` function requires some metadata about the signature of your functor's call operator, and it expects these metadata to be provided as type aliases in your functor class. For instance:

```
template<typename T>
class printer
{
public:

    // These metadata must be present in order for bind1st and bind2nd to work...
    typedef void result_type;
    typedef T first_argument_type;
    typedef string const& second_argument_type;

    void operator()(T a, string const& kd) const
//                                         ^^^^^ // Bonus advice #1:
//                                               // This could and should be
//                                               // const-qualified
//                              ^^^^^
//                              Bonus advice #2: why not taking by
//                              reference to const here? ;)
    {
        cout<<a<<endl;
    }
};
```

A simpler way of achieving the above is to use the (also deprecated) class template `std::binary_function` as a base class, and let that class template define the appropriate type aliases:

```
template<typename T>
class printer : public std::binary_function<T, string const&, void>
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
public:
    void operator()(T a, string const& kd) const
    {
        cout<<a<<endl;
    }
};
```

But again, please consider putting `std::bind1st()`, `std::bind2nd()`, as well as `std::unary_function` and `std::binary_function`, back in the drawer. They are superseded by C++11's more powerful support for functional programming.

Comment: Going from my link, it seems `std::ptr_fun` can save some work here.

Comment: @chris: You're right, I actually checked only the accepted answer ;) Will edit, thank you

Comment: @chris: I opted for a more thorough edit in the end. `std::bind()` is the right way to go, did not want to insist too much on other solutions. Thank you anyway

Comment: @AndyProwl 
tried the elegant way, worked half-way then flopped when i tried to call f1(5), this time with this error:

[Error] C:\MinGW\include\C__~1\488DF2~1.0\backward\binders.h:154:29: error: no match for call to '(const printer<int>) (const first_argument_type&, const second_argument_type&)'    { return op(__x, value); }                          ^

im not trying to be spoon fed but, i am really stumped.

Comment: @MauriceRodriguez Try declaring the `operator()` as const.

Comment: @AndyProwl thanks for saving my ass twice today man!
i knew the use of ++11's bind() because my compiler supports it, but my school's computers don't, so i have to learn both. :)