# Why doesn't std::bind1st work on free functions?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm wondering why the following gives me an error:

```
bool is_divisible(int by, int n)
{
    return (n % by) == 0;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    cout << count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), bind1st(is_divisible, 2)) << endl;
}
```

However, if I use `bind(is_divisible, 2, _1)`, it works. I'm wondering what the technical difference is between `bind1st` and `bind` that causes the latter to work in this case?

Comment: A phrase like "gives me an error" should be immediately followed by the error itself.

Comment: @Adam The compiler spews out quite a bit, but the errors seem to center around `error: 'bool (*)(int, int)' is not a class, struct, or union type`. Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with bind1st to parse that. Interestingly enough if I assign is_divisible to an `std::function<bool(int, int)>` and then use bind1st on that, then it works. I'm interested in learning about what's going on behind the scenes that enables bind1st to work in some of these cases, and not in others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use bind1st and bind2nd?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418756/how-to-use-bind1st-and-bind2nd)

Comment: The difference is that bind1st works on "class, struct or union" types, while bind *also* works on functions. Functions are not, as the error message says, "class, struct or union types". bind1st nominally requires a class object which derives from the standard class binary_function. Such objects redefine "operator()" so that they are syntactically similar to functions.

Comment: @rici I agree with everything you say except "derives from the standard class binary_function". There is no such requirement. All you need is an `operator()(x, y)` overload.

Comment: @adam: my old battered copy of C++ PL, 3rd edition, says "These adapters all have a common structure relying on the function object bases *unary_function* and *binary_function*"; as I recall, Stroustrup expected them to require the various typedefs provided by those base classes (`first_argument_type`, etc.). It's been a long time since I've used C++89, and I'm pretty sure that these days an implementation of `bind1st` could figure that stuff out, but I'm pretty sure I remember them *not* working with just an operator() overload. Anyway, my uncertainty was why I said "nominally".

Comment: @rici I've certainly used them without the base classes, in C++03. I suspect templates removed that requirement. The bound argument type T just has to be convertible to the functor's 1st argument type.

Comment: @adam: OK, I tried with c++03. They don't need the base classes, certainly, but they need the typedefs. You could just add the typedefs, but deriving from binary_function<result, arg1, arg2> is less typing and saves you from remembering how to spell "second_argument_type". I'm sticking with "nominally" :) (Besides, I can't edit that comment any more.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[bind1st](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind1st/):

> This function constructs an unary function object from the **binary
>   function object** op by binding its first parameter to the fixed value
>   x.

(emphasis mine)

A [function object](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/) is an object that's supposed to be used as a function (i.e. overloads `operator()`). So `bind1st` is not supposed to work with free functions.

It works when wrapped by `std::function` because that then becomes a function *object*.

Since you're just learning this, use `bind` instead. No point in learning a deprecated interface.

Comment: So in pre-C++11, the solution is to use a combination of `std::bind1st` and `std::ptr_fun`, i.e pass the first argument as:  `std::bind1st(std::ptr_fun(is_divisible),2)`. In C++11, simply use `std::bind` as the OP already knows.